# In Azure DevOps Process Editor how do you link custom work items types?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, I would like to create a some new workitem types and related them in a hierarchy (e.g. MyWorkItemGrandParent -> MyWorkItemParent -> MyWorkItemChild). In TFS you could modify the XAML to achieve this but I can't find how to do this in Azure DevOps.

I've tried hunting through the MS help and hunting around the Azure DevOps Process Editor to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not create custom work item types in a hierarchy. But you can crate [Area Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops) and assign the Area Path of work items to an area path you defined.
Area paths allow you to group work items by team, product, or feature area. 
Please note that while you can assign the same area path to more than one team, this can cause problems if two teams claim ownership over the same set of work items.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage your hierarchy with backlogs, you can edit existing or create new backlog levels with process editor: [Customize your backlogs or boards (Inheritance process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-backlogs-boards?view=azure-devops)